# Proof in partial differential equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Prove that :
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_a^b u(x,t)\,dx + A(u(b,t))-A(u(a,t))=0$$ for all $a,b$

is equal with

$$\int_0^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}[ u\psi_t + A(u)\psi_x]\,dx\,dt=0$$

where $$u_t+a(u)u_x=0$$ and $a(u)=A'(u)$

Any ideas ?

Comment: Looks like you need to bring the differentiation into the integral (check the conditions!) or use FTC

Comment: Are you trying to prove both equalities or just the one?

Comment: I am trying to prove that equalities are equivalent